# Asymptotic Distribution of Quantiles

Tags: limits, probability-theory, asymptotics

In order to prove that the sample $p$-percentile $x_p, p \in [0,1]$ from a sample of $n$ is asymptotically normally distributed as $n\to\infty$, it is necessary to show the following two limits. They are given in my reading without proof.

\begin{align}
(*) \;\;\; \ln\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \frac{n!}{(np-1)!(n-np)!} p^{np-0.5} (1-p)^{n-np+0.5} \right) \to \mathrm{a\ constant} \\
(**) \;\;\; (np-1) \ln \left( 1+\frac{z\sqrt{1-p}}{\sqrt{np}} \right) + (n-np)\ln\left( 1-\frac{z\sqrt p}{\sqrt{n(1-p)}} \right) \to -\frac{z^2}{2}
\end{align}

Assume that $np$ is an integer. I could not figure out how these results are obtained. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: It looks messy but straightforward.  Probably you could start by breaking apart the log in the first one and using Stirling's formula, and for the second expand the logs using Taylor series to 2 (maybe 3? probably 2) terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using Stirling's approx. for factorials the first expression can be written as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\times \frac{1}{e}\times\frac{n^n}{(np-1)^{np-0.5}(n(1-p))^{n(1-p)+0.5}}\times p^{np-0.5}(1-p)^{n(1-p)+0.5}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\times \frac{1}{e}\times\Big(\frac{np}{np-1}\Big)^{np-0.5}
\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\times \frac{1}{e}\times e$$

2. Using Taylor expansion the second expression is

$$(np-1)\Bigg(\frac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p})}-\frac{z^2}{2n}\frac{1-p}{p} +O(n^{-3}) \Bigg)+n(1-p)\Bigg(-\frac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{p}{1-p}}-\frac{z^2}{2n}\frac{p}{1-p}+O(n^{-3})\Bigg)=\Bigg(-\frac{z^2}{2}(1-p)-\frac{z^2}{2}p\Bigg)+o(1)\rightarrow -\frac{z^2}{2}$$